# total variation of sinc function

Tags: improper-integrals, total-variation

The total variation of differentiable function $f$ is defined by
$$||f||_V=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f'(t)|\:dt$$

I must show
$$||f||_V = \infty$$ if $$f(t)=\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$$

In other words I need to solve
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big|\frac{\pi t\cos(\pi t)-\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t^2}\Big|\: dt$$
$$2\int_0^{\infty}\Big|\frac{t\cos(t)-\sin(t)}{t^2}\Big|\:dt$$
and here I don't know where to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: in the interval $(2n\pi-\frac {\pi } 4,2n\pi+\frac {\pi } 4)$ verify that $|t \cos t -\sin t| >\frac {t-1} {\sqrt 2}$. Now integrate over this interval and sum over $n$.

Comment: Could you give me another hint for how to verify the inequality? I don't know any trig formulas that would work because of the $t$ in front of the cosine, and I tried squaring both sides but that's going nowhere.

Comment: @RyanGreyling Between $-\pi /4$ and $+\pi /4$ we have $\cos t >\frac  1{\sqrt 2}$ and $\sin t <\frac  1{\sqrt 2}$